# DATE() MONTH() etc. functions slow down query

Tags: mysql, sql, date, datetime

I have a table Posts with a lot of records. I want to show user today posts, it is about 3-4 k.

**creation_date** - `DATETIME` field. This field has index.

In my query i simple filter records with query:

```
 SELECT posts.title AS post_title
 WHERE date(posts.creation_date) = DATE('2016-06-11')
```

This query performing 14 seconds.

Then i changed it to:

```
SELECT posts.title AS post_title 
WHERE pending_posts.creation_date > CONVERT('2016-06-11', DATETIME) 
AND pending_posts.creation_date < CONVERT('2016-06-11', DATETIME) + INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

And it takes 0.2 seconds...

Why this happens ? 
And how do i convert `MONTH(posts.creation_date)` or `YEAR(posts.creation_date)` because they slow down queries too, but i need show posts per month and per year.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

it is a very bad idea to use functions on a field in the where clause. when you do this MySQL must read ALL rows (FULL TABLE SCAN) to see whats the result anfter the function and the its compare it with the constant.

Its much better to use function on the constant part the its convert only one time and the query can use a index.

**for one DAY**

```
SELECT ... WHERE datetimefield between '2016-01-05 00:00:00' AND '2016-01-05 23:59:59';
```

or

```
SELECT ... WHERE datetimefield between '2016-01-05 00:00:00' AND '2016-01-05 00:00:00' + INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

**for one month**

```
SELECT ... WHERE datetimefield between '2016-06-01 00:00:00' AND '2016-06-01 00:00:00' + INTERVAL 1 MONTH;
```

You can see the work of your query in the execution plan:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT posts.title AS post_title
 WHERE date(posts.creation_date) = DATE('2016-06-11');
```

and

```
EXPLAIN SELECT posts.title AS post_title 
WHERE pending_posts.creation_date > CONVERT('2016-06-11', DATETIME) 
AND pending_posts.creation_date < CONVERT('2016-06-11', DATETIME) + INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

Comment: @Arti - i have some infos in my answer